# Why do I get AttributeError when I run this code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from collections import Counter
import re
  

s = open( 'filename.txt', 'r')
words = re.findall('\w+', s.lower())
c = Counter(words)

for word, freq in c.most_common(10):
    print(word, ':' , freq)
```

I get this error when the code is executed but I don't know why. What can I do to correct this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./find_occurences_in_a_txt_file.py", line 9, in <module>
        words = re.findall( '\w+' , s.lower())
    AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Because `s` isn't a string, it's a file (technically an `_io.TextIOWrapper`, as per the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` isn't string, it's a file, like EntagledLoops said.

You can do `s.read().lower()`. Please comment if this is not the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the file object into a string. You can do this with `.read()`. Also, you should use `with` instead of `open` when handling files so that the file is automatically closed when you are done with it.
Finally, you need a raw string (starting with `r`) for your regex:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
  
words = []
with open( 'filename.txt', 'r') as s:
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', s.read().lower())
c = Counter(words)

for word, freq in c.most_common(10):
    print(word, ':' , freq)
```